# What is the difference between 讲课 and 演讲?

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference? 演讲, according to my dictionary, is either a speech (in general, like a politician would give) or a lecture (at a university or so), while 讲课 is just the lecture, as in a lesson. Is that the correct way to distinguish the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**讲课**

is strictly a *verb* meaning:

> to teach/to give lessons (in ....)

**演讲**

can be a noun meaning

> speech

or a verb meaning

> to give a speech

Both could be translated as: **lecture**, if you wanted.

The biggest difference is the 课 in 讲课 - meaning class or course.

Answer (score 1):

講課 usually exclusively refers to a lecture in a school or university, while 演講 is not restricted to such context. Every kind of (somewhat formal) "speech" may be said a 演講.